# Get default route from dependency injection services

Tags: php, symfony

I am using request object in twig extension class to get the current route. For instance, having the following url:

```
http://www.localhost/project/user/page/2
```

Inside of the twig extension I'm able to get user/page/2 string and do something with it.

The problem arises when I wanna get the default route using the same method, which I have to do. For example, accessing the following url:

```
http://www.localhost/project/user
```

I want to get `user/page/1` string inside the twig extension class, and not just `user`.

The controller looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route(name="user",
 *        default="user/page/1")
 */
```

Is there a way to achieve that? Or do I have to stop using default routes?

Write a comment if you need more explanation, it's 9AM here in Poland and I'm sleeping yet.

Answer (score 0):

The [@Route documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#usage) explains that you can do this for set a default page number:

```
/**
 * @Route("/project/user/page/{page}",
 *     name="user",
 *     defaults={"page" = 1},
 *     requirements={"page" = "\d+"}
 * )
 */
```